# Chilli plant Potted in the balcony

Tags: chili

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbacy.jpg)My chilli plant leaves are getting wrinkly. I live in Melbourne, Australia.
They are in a pot in the balcony. This has been going on for a few weeks. Being watered everyday. Have sprayed them with some eco-oil organic pesticide but haven’t made any difference.
Thinking of cutting out all the bad leaves. Have not changed pots or anything

[image: Chilli with some leaves wrinkled]

Comment: How much sun are they picking up every day? Are the leaves better now?